# How to make intellisense in WebStorm work with wrapped React functional component

Tags: reactjs, functional-programming, ide, webstorm

I try to use React.memo with functional Component. It works great. 
However, the intellisense WebStorm seems not to work with wrapped component like `React.memo(MyComponent)`

Does anyone know how to overcome it ?

Comment: Currently, these components are not supported in WebStorm. Please follow this issue for updates: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-38747

Comment: thanks @EkaterinaPrigara, i hope they will soon implement this feature. It is very annoying to develop React Component without code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I found myself the solution to this problem is using [prop-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types)

In the following example, IntelliSense in WebStorm does not recognize the component `Hello`, but it can recognize the component `Hi`

```js
import React, { memo } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

export const Hello = React.memo(({ name }) => <div>Hello {name}</div>);
export const Hi = React.memo(({ name }) => <div>Hi {name}</div>);

Hi.PropTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string
};
```

[View on Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/proptypes-and-reactmemo-g40qu)